# Cassandra JMX is not listening on eth0 even if I add JVM opts to cassandra-env.sh

Tags: java, jmx

I am using DSE. My cassandra JMX is only listening on localhost even if I add `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP>"`

- My firewall is off
- My SELINUX is disabled
- Hostname is added in DNS
- Added to /etc/hosts too.

DSE service is running on eth0, but JMX is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some JVM flags:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port>
```